# How to map o365 libraries to Win10 quick access links w/o IE

Tags: windows, powershell, google-chrome, scripting, microsoft-edge

We have the Powershell script below which allows us to map a Sharepoint library and the user's Onedrive to user's quick access links in Windows 10. This requires IE and since that's no longer supported I'm wondering if there is a similar solution using Edge or Chrome?

```
$ie = Start-Process -file iexplore -arg 'https://mycompanyname.sharepoint.com/sites/Archived' -PassThru -WindowStyle Minimized
sleep 8
$ie.Kill()
$ie = Start-Process -file iexplore -arg "https://mycompanyname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/${env:username}_mycompanyname_org\Documents" -Passthru -WindowStyle Minimized
sleep 8
$ie.Kill()
$folder = '\\mycompanyname.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\Archived'
$folder2 = '\\mycompanyname-my.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\personal\' + $env:username + '_mycompanyname_org\Documents'
$QuickAccess = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$QuickAccess.Namespace($folder).Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome")
$QuickAccess.Namespace($folder1).Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome")
```

Comment: You are running the command line options of iexplorer.  Here are the command lines for Chrome : https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Since you're just making shortcuts, do you need to open them at all? You can use edge exactly the same way by replacing `iexplore` with `msedge`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I tried replacing iexplore with msedge, but got error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." It's referencing this line:
```$QuickAccess.Namespace($folder).Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome")```

Comment: I think IE just creates an o365 login token (but I don't have anything to test with). Check the minimized edge pages and see if they're asking you to log into sharepoint? See if powershell can access the folders too like `Test-Path $folder`. If it returns false, try it once with the user's O365 credential like `Test-Path $folder -Credential (Get-Credential)`, though I'm not sure sharepoint still allows basic auth this way

Comment: Running Test-Path $folder resulted in false. When I ran Path $folder -Credential (Get-Credential) I got:
```Test-Path : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. Perform 
the operation again without specifying credentials.

 test-path $folder -Credential (Get-Credential)

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand```

Comment: Do the edge pages actually open the sharepoint folder? You may need to allow authentication to internet webdav like this - some orgs set IE to do this separately: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/error-access-network-drive-mapped-web-share

Comment: Yes, it opens fine in Edge w/o requiring any creds. Strange.

Comment: It seems that the validation modes are different in IE and Edge. You can try Cpt.Whale's suggestion to allow authentication to see if it works.

Comment: @YuZhou I tried that and got the error:

```Test-Path : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. Perform 
the operation again without specifying credentials.
At line:1 char:1
+ test-path $folder -Credential (Get-Credential)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand```